# Is there a faster way to add rows in C# dictionary other than dictionary.add?

Tags: c#, dictionary

We are using dictionary with key value pair both as string, Dictionary has millions of rows been added in a foreach loop. Profiler results show dictionary.add taking elapsed time in **minutes** for **million** plus hits.

Below is the method for reference.

```
public virtual Dictionary<string, string> CreateDictionaryRow(string[] row)
{
    Dictionary<string, string> dictionaryRow = new Dictionary<string, string>();

    foreach (ColumnMappingBO item in this.Layout.Items)
    {

        string value = string.Empty;
        if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(item.ColumnPosition))
        {
            if (item.ColumnPosition == "ZZ")
            {
                value = string.Empty;
            }
            else
            {
                if (LayoutPosition.TryGetValue(item.ColumnID, out Ordinal))
                {
                    if (row.Length > Ordinal)
                    {
                        if (row[Ordinal] != null)
                        {
                            value = row[Ordinal];
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }
        dictionaryRow.Add(item.ColumnNameID, value);
    }
    return dictionaryRow;
}
```

All the code lines are fine, performance is impacted when dictionaryRow.Add() is executed. Let know how do we optimise adding rows to dictionary, any external custom library which can be used ?

Comment: Something with hashing, buckets and resizing. These operations take time. Why do you think it can be done faster? Why are you using a dictionary? Did you try [setting a large initial capacity](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/tk84bxf4(v=vs.110).aspx)?

Comment: I don't think it's the .Add method that slows you down - all it does it just adds 2 strings to the Dictionary so that's not the source of your problem... All the code between where you initialize and call dictionary.Add needs improvements possibly

Comment: Have you considered changing the key type to something more efficiently comparable than string?  I had a similar problem the other day, where a Dictionary<> was keyed with Remoting objects.  In my case, changing the key _to_ a string gave an enormous performance improvement (over 100 times quicker).

Comment: Thanks Jon. I meant each call to dictionary.add (), if we consider takes 0.015ms and multiplied by millions of hits, it shoots up the time in minutes.

Key type is string. is there any alternative solution than .add() ?

Comment: @chint There's no alternative to Add(), but there _is_ an alternative to _what_ you add.  A string key of several characters would be less efficient than, say, some integer identifier.  Can you change the key to something like this?

Answer (score 0):

I would try changing this into a LINQ query.

Maybe something like this:

```
    public Dictionary<string, string> CreateDictionaryRow(string[] row)
    {
        return this.Layout.Items.ToDictionary(item => item.ColumnNameID, 
                                    item => GetValue(item, row));;
    }

    private string GetValue(ColumnMappingBO item, string[] row)
    {
        string value = string.Empty;
        if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(item.ColumnPosition))
        {
            if (item.ColumnPosition == "ZZ")
            {
                value = string.Empty;
            }
            else
            {
                if (LayoutPosition.TryGetValue(item.ColumnID, out Ordinal))
                {
                    if (row.Length > Ordinal)
                    {
                        if (row[Ordinal] != null)
                        {
                            value = row[Ordinal];
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }

        return value;
    }
```

Comment: Thanks Milosz, performance is the same. Let know if anything else can be tested.

Answer (score 0):

One thing to experiment is how many unique hashcodes item.ColumnNameId generates.
if there's a lot of collisions you are basically doing the same as iterating over a linkedlist until you reach the end and then add the object at the end.

Here's the code that is called when you call dictionary.Add() taken from http://referencesource.microsoft.com/#q=Dictionary

So with a lot of collisions you start looping and comparing keys *a lot* and with such a large Dictionary you can expect some collisions.

```
void Insert(TKey key, TValue value, bool add) {        
            if (buckets == null) Initialize(0);
            int hashCode = comparer.GetHashCode(key) & 0x7FFFFFFF;
            int targetBucket = hashCode % buckets.Length;

            for (int i = buckets[targetBucket]; i >= 0; i = entries[i].next) {
                if (entries[i].hashCode == hashCode && comparer.Equals(entries[i].key, key)) {
                    entries[i].value = value;
                    version++;
                    return;
                } 
}
```